# Preguntas sin responder de mis etiquetas ordenadas por actividad

Tags: bug, característica-nueva, estado-por-diseño

Estoy usando un filtro avanzado para poder ver las preguntas de mis etiquetas que están sin responder y poder ordenadas por actividad y creo que la opción `isanswered` no está funcionando correctamente porque siguen apareciendo respuestas que tienen respuestas aceptadas o con puntuación positiva.

Para quitar las aceptadas puedo usar `hasaccepted:no` pero no tengo forma de quitar de los resultados las que tienen una respuesta con votos positivos ¿quizás es un bug?

- Las opciones de filtrado que utilizo son:

  ```
  is:question hasaccepted:no isanswered:0 intags:mine
  ```
- La url resultante y que tengo en mis favoritos es [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3Aquestion%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20isanswered%3A0%20intags%3Amine)

Por cierto, sería fantástico contar con esta funcionalidad desde la sección "**Sin responder**", por ejemplo con un nuevo tab "**Mis etiquetas (activas)**" porque en la la vista estándar se ordenan por puntuación y siempre salen las mismas preguntas antiguas que difícilmente se podrán responder.

**Actualización:** Me he fijado en el comportamiento de `isanswered:0` y si que quita de los resultados las preguntas con respuestas puntuadas pero hay veces que tarda unos minutos después de recibir los puntos pero sigue sin comportarse como se explica en la documentación

> `isanswered: yes/true/1` retorna solo preguntas que tengan al menos **una respuesta aceptada** o con **votos positivos**; `no/false/0` retorna solo preguntas que **no tengan respuesta aceptada** o **con votos positivos**.

Comment: no se si eso que comentas puede estar relacionado con esto que comunique tiempo atras -> http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366/sistema-de-busqueda-filtrar-por-tag-no-funciona-correctamente-en-algunos-ca tambien lo deje en el meta en ingles pero aun sigue igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad el filtro está funcionando bien hay un pequeño detalle en la url que pones y es que tiene una condicion adicional que es `tab=active` el cual está modificando los resultados de la búsqueda. Su significado:

> Preguntas formuladas, con respuesta o actualizadas recientemente

Aquí te dejo una foto de los resultados de tu filtro y otra de lo mismo pero ya sin el `tab=active`

Para la url

https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3Aquestion%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20isanswered%3A0%20intags%3Amine

[image: filtro de la pregunta]

y ahora el mismo filtro sin especificarle el tab, para obtenerlo sólo tuve que presionar <kbd>enter</kbd> en los resultados de la búsqueda y este parece "olvidar" esa condición adicional

Para la url

https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3Ano+isanswered%3A0+intags%3Amine

[image: filtro arreglado]

Creo que este último es lo que quieres lograr

Es curioso que esa condición no se encuentre en la [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) sin embargo solo altera los resultados si se especifica en la query de esta forma `?tab=active` en lugar de `tab:active` por lo que me hace pensar que es un bug en el sistema de navegación que está interfiriendo con los resultados de la búsqueda.

Solución a largo plazo, reportalo en el [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) de StackExchange.

Solución a corto plazo, usa el [filtro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20isanswered%3A0%20intags%3Amine) correcto en su lugar